# How to return the most used id of struct

Tags: c, struct

I have this struct and I am trying to come up with an algorithm that returns the **IDcli** that was used most.

In the image below *getCli()* would return **33**

[image]

```
typedef struct 
{
    int ID;
    int IDcli;
    char Name[50];
} Example;

Example e[5][5];

int getCli() {
    int i=0,ID=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(e[i][0].IDcli>0)
            /* 
                each time it passes on same IDcli it increments
                but the IDcli isnt constant
            */

    }

    return ID;
}
```

Comment: you got to show some effort first.

Comment: `Example e[5][5];` means that `e[5][5]` in the rightmost column is indexed out of bounds.

Comment: @joop i edited the post

Comment: If it is any arbitrary number, which seems to be the case, you have to create an array large enough to contain all the possible combinations of `IDcli`. 

So in order to not consume extreme amounts of memory, you need to state some restriction to how many possible value combinations there are. If this is not known, you'll have to use a generic, suitable container class such as a hash table.

Answer (score -1):

```
   #include <unordered_map>
   #include <algorithm>
   using namespace std;

   typedef struct 
   {
    int ID;
    int IDcli;
    char Name[50];
   } Example;

   Example e[5][5];

   int getCli() {
    int i=0,ID=0;
    unordered_map<int, int> m;
    for (; i<5; ++i) { 
        for (int j=0; j<5; ++j) {
            if (m.find(e[i][j].IDcli) != m.end()) {
                m[e[i][j].IDcli]++;
            } else {
                m[e[i][j].IDcli] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (unordered_map<int, int>::iterator it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); ++it) {
        ID = max(ID, it->first);
    }
    return ID;
   }
```

Comment: Nice & complex code, but that seems to be c++, right?